# What are the unique contributions of Sri Madvacharya?

Tags: madhvacharya

We see often tattva Vada philosophy says five fold difference, Narayana Supremacy, Souls subservience and Brahma infinite auspicious qualities which is always complete.  More importantly Reality of the world.

what are the unique contributions of Sri Madvacharya?

Comment: Its the concept of Taaratamya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ontology of tattvada premaya stotra

> > vishnusarvottamatha aakkila patha gathitha sarva vedhaabhidheyaha
> > srinatha sathgunabdhi
> > jaggadhudhyalayapadhihi ashtta karthaha
> > antharathma
> > brahma adhyaaha uccha nechaha  haricharana rathaha
> > pancha bedha prapancha..
> > satya stribhumsha bhavaha
> > sthatham ananpadha yogyadha swabhavaha ..
> > jivahas thrigunya bajyaha
> > paramagathi yujihaha nitya panthaha tamoghaha
> > satthva thirkakshye mokshaye nija sukha neyathi sadhanam gnana bhakthihi
> > isttam deivam mukundha paraama guru rashov maruthir madhva nama visvam thabhayam uphapyam niamitham ithi ayam tattvadaha
> > imam acharya govinda vinayee jana vanchitha vethyemayee tattva vadassya premaya >>nava mallikam

Meaning

Vishnu is supreme all words, letters and sentence in all languages including vedas indicate Vishnu only that is why he is supreme
He is Lakhsmi pathi one above all satva, rajas and tamas guna,
He is creater,sustainer,destroyer,doer of all,bestower of gnana (knowledge) , aagnana (delusion), entangler and giver of moksha(Salvation)
so he is called eight actor.
He is the inner soul of all beign
Brahma to lowest beign have grades or levels All have to obey Sri Hari(Vishnu)
Universe is of Five fold difference (Iswara, Jiva, Jada) triangle have (Iswara-Jiva, Iswara-Jada, Jiva-Jada, Jiva-Jiva, Jada-Jada)
Male or Female is attached to soul(attma)(not of linga, sushma or sthula deha)
Jiva will always have base quality this wont be differing (essential nature or vakthithva) even in moksha,
Jiva is different in their experience of bliss in moksha. Moksha Jiva will have difference based on nature
Jivas are affected by 3 qualities (sattva, rajas and tamas)
because of the above some jiva eligible for moksha, some will always be in cycle, some go to andhamas
Only pure sattvik souls reach moksha procedure is knowledge and bhakthi
Mukundha (vishnu) is deliverer of moksha he is the God. Guru is Hanuman named as Madhva one who controls or
sustains the universe
The above is essence tattva vada given by bannaje govindharchaya on request of his disciple
the stotra is named as tattva vada premaya nava mallika

Sri bharathi Ramana Mukhy pranathargatha krishnarpnamasthu.

(Dedicated to the god who reside inside all our lord of life breath and his consort(mukhyaprana and bharathi) that is krishna)