# What's the difference between Dvaita and the Abrahamic faiths?

Tags: philosophy, other-religions, dvaita

In Dvaita there is Atman and Brahman, while in the Abrahamic faiths there is soul and God. 
These systems sound similar, but I assume they are in fact different?

According to Hindu philosophers, **what are** the basic differences?

Comment: First, in dvaita (dualistic) philosophy, God is seen as an extra-cosmic supreme Person, separate from the universe. The Abrahamic religions are the same. They assert that the Godhead is an extra-cosmic supreme Person separate from the universe also.

Comment: Creation by God is ex nihilo (out of nothing) in Abrahamic faiths. In dvaita, creation by God is from prakriti. I think Abrahamic faiths dont have concept of reincarnation, while dvaita does. These are some differences I can recall offhand.

Comment: Abrahmic faiths believe in one resurrection of departed ones on judgement day for hell or heaven, while Hinduism has eternal reincarnation of souls and moving across hell, earth or heaven depending on their Karmas. Creation is 6k years old according to Jewish calendar but according to Hinduism its 5k years of Kaliyuga of 28th chaturyuga of 7th Manvantar.

Comment: When I had posted this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37143/3869) that was closed stating that it was off topic, because we should not discuss other faiths like Buddhism here.  Why this question is allowed to remain by the moderators so far? May I know?

Answer (score 1):

In Abhramic faith God is outside and above all.

1. He is not inside everything.

2. He is not the doer of souls action and hence free will

3. No rebirth.. one life

4. Never accepted or even aware of Vedas

In dvaita or tattvavada

1. God is inside every atom

2. God is the doer of the souls action but all results of actions are attributed to souls (its like Owner and worker) even though sales person sells a product the actual profit or loss goes to owner(Hence Gita fundamental theme of not expecting results of action is the key for ending rebirth cycle)

3. Rebirth and hence karma based

4. Vedas are the only source to know about God.

These are the obvious difference.

But I believe in ten commandment the below is said 
there are similarities in creation God sowed the seed in the garden of eden, the seeds are the souls. God doesn't create souls and also basic matter that build material world.

Hence not responsible for fundamental nature of order of the material world These are obvious main difference and similarities, In addition to the above there are many difference in worship and other things.

http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33310/